# Dodge failing in violin plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the congruence effects (incongruent minus congruent) as a violin plot per combination of stimulus age and response type. This is what my code looks like so far. I am not yet satisfied with the representation. How can I change it so that for each of the four conditions (adult frown, adult smile, child frown, child smile) I get the corresponding violin plot horizontally next to each other? Thanks in advance for the help. Attached is the code and an excerpt from the data frame.

[violin plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBq6C.png)

```
dataset$congruency_effect <- ifelse(dataset$congruency == "congruent", dataset$avgAmplitude, -dataset$avgAmplitude)

p <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = stimulusResponse, y = congruency_effect, fill = congruency_effect, group = stimulusAge)) + 
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), size = 3, stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#F8766D", "#00BFC4")) +
  ggtitle("Conventional EEG 350-450 ms") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5, 5)) +
  facet_wrap(~stimulusAge, scales = "free_x")

EEG_Conventional450_age_response <- p + theme(
  # Set the plot title and axis labels to APA style
  plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16),
  axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14),
  # Set the axis tick labels to APA style
  axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
  # Set the legend title and labels to APA style
  legend.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14),
  legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
  # Set the plot and panel backgrounds to white
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
  plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white")
)

EEG_Conventional450_age_response
```

[excerpt data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqtpV.png)

- several permutations of arguments in ggplot

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the grouping aesthetic. Remove it, and your plot works.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)
dataset <- data.frame(stimulusResponse =  rep(c("frown", "smile"), each = 20), 
                      congruency_effect = rnorm(40), 
                      stimulusAge = rep(c("baby", "adult"), 20))

## removed group = stimulusAge
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = stimulusResponse, y = congruency_effect)) + 
  geom_violin() +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), size = 3, stat = "summary") +
  facet_wrap(~stimulusAge, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: love you man, thanks! however, fill = congruency must remain, right? Get a mistake otherwise.

Comment: @poldi As you can see, I have also removed it. In fact, you're filling with a continuous variable, although it should be single values. Not sure why it doesn't work for you to remove it though.

Comment: now it does. don`t know what it was. thanks man for the quick fix. enjoy your day